# Getting session data with a condition on Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I making a login session with one condition if User is not found in Table A then start looking in Table B, here's the code:

```
$EMP_NO = strtoupper($this->input->post('empcd'));
        $passwd = strtoupper($this->input->post('password'));

        $getUser = $this->db->query("SELECT EMP_NO, EN_NAME, UPPER(cryptit.decrypt(PASSWORD,EMP_NO)) PASSWORD2, MAILADDRESS FROM tkgw_user_information WHERE EMP_NO = '$EMP_NO'");

        if ($getUser->num_rows() == 1) {
            $user = $getUser->row();

            if ($passwd == $user->PASSWORD2) {

                $session_data = [
                    'iduser' => $user->EMP_NO,
                    'nama' => $user->EN_NAME,
                    'empcd' => $user->EMP_NO,
                    'email' => $user->MAILADDRESS,
                    'loginuser' => TRUE,
                ];

                $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Welcome! ' . $user->EN_NAME);
                redirect(base_url('dashboard'));
            } else {
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Wrong Password!');
                redirect(base_url('sign-in'));  
            }

            } else {
                $findUser = $this->db->query("SELECT UPPER(EMP_NO), EN_NAME, UPPER(PASSWORD) PASSWORD2, MAILADDRESS FROM ITSJ_USER_ACCOUNT WHERE EMP_NO = '$EMP_NO'");
                if ($findUser->num_rows() == 1) {
                    $userx = $findUser->row();

                    if ($passwd == $userx->PASSWORD2) {

                        $session_data = [
                            'iduser' => $userx->EMP_NO,
                            'nama' => $userx->EN_NAME,
                            'empcd' => $userx->EMP_NO,
                            'email' => $userx->MAILADDRESS,
                            'loginuser' => TRUE,
                        ];
                        $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Welcome! ' . $userx->EN_NAME);
                        redirect(base_url('dashboard'));

                    } else {
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Wrong Password!');
                        redirect(base_url('sign-in'));  
                    }
                }else{
                        $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'User not avalable!');
                        redirect(base_url('sign-in'));
                }
            }
        }
```

With those code I able to login via Table B when the User is not exist in Table A, but every time I'm switching page it keeps asking me to login again, seems like the session is over or destroyed.
But if I login via Table A (the first condition), the session remain intact.

Can you please help me finding the solution, thank you.

Edit:

checking if user logged or not on each page:

```
if ($this->session->userdata('iduser') == NULL) {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('Warning', 'Please Login First');
    redirect(base_url('sign-in'));
}
```

Comment: Same array, same function, I found nothing wrong with the above code. Could you post the logic that check user logged in or not?

Comment: @VanTho I add checking user logged, check the edit above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the caused that keeping User on the table 2 logged out when they redirected to the other pages, when I show *session's all_userdata* I noticed that the EMP_NO returned empty, So I remove the 'UPPER' part from 'UPPER(EMP_NO)' on the second query, and it works now.

thank you all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

> Try Below code

```
Public function check_login($table_name){
    $EMP_NO = strtoupper($this->input->post('empcd'));
    $passwd = strtoupper($this->input->post('password'));
     return  $this->db->query("SELECT EMP_NO, EN_NAME, UPPER(cryptit.decrypt(PASSWORD,EMP_NO)) PASSWORD2, MAILADDRESS FROM ".$table_name." WHERE EMP_NO = '$EMP_NO'");

}
Public function login(){
    $table1 = "tkgw_user_information";
    $table2 = "ITSJ_USER_ACCOUNT";

    $result = $this->check_login($table1);
    if($result->num_rows()==0){
        $result = $this->check_login($table2);
        if($result->num_rows()==0){
             $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'User not available!');
                redirect('sign-in'); 
        }
    }
    $user = $result->row();
    if ($passwd == $user->PASSWORD2) {
                $session_data = [
                    'iduser' => $user->EMP_NO,
                    'nama' => $user->EN_NAME,
                    'empcd' => $user->EMP_NO,
                    'email' => $user->MAILADDRESS,
                    'loginuser' => TRUE,
                ];
                $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
                $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'Welcome! ' . $user->EN_NAME);
                redirect('dashboard');
    }else{
         $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Wrong Password!');
        redirect('sign-in'); 
    }
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @Boominathan Elango thank you for your answer, I tried your code and login with my account on the Table 1 but it always returned 'Wrong Password!', if I login with my account on the Table 2 it returns 'User not available!'